# How To Determine Which WHERE Clause Was True In A Linq Statement

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a way in LINQ to tell which WHERE clause(s) hit?  I have an object called Company, it can in turn have multiple BillTo objects, each BillTo object can have multiple Generator objects.

```
Company
|
+-- BillTo1 - named First
|    |
|    |-- Generator1 - named Alpha
|    |
|    +-- Generator2 - named Beta
|
+-- BillTo2 - named Second
     |
     +-- Generator3 - name Gamma
```

Here is the linq statement (stripped out extra stuff for other where statements):

```
bool HaveCompany = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Company);
var AllData = (from co in db.Companies
             join bt in db.Billtoes on co.ID equals bt.CompanyID into bts
             from b in bts.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join gn in db.Generators on b.ID equals gn.BillToID into gns
             from g in gns.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where co.Active == true
             && (
                co.Name.Contains(HaveCompany ? Company : co.Name) ||
                b.Name.Contains(HaveCompany ? Company : b.Name) ||
                g.Name.Contains(HaveCompany ? Company : g.Name)
             )
             select new {
                 CompanyID = co.ID,
                 BillTo = b,
                 Generator = g,
                 Name = co.Name,
             }).ToList();
```

The problem is, it finds everything correctly.  If I find the "Name" match on the BillTo, I don't really need to do "Generator = g" nor vice-versa if I find it on the Generator I don't need to do "BillTo = b".

So if ther was a way to know which WHERE clause(s) was hit, then I would add the appropriate b or g to the result.  I know I could reiterate through AFTER I get the results and re-check each of the 7 fields I am actually sending in as WHERE clauses, but that seems like too much extra code.  Perhaps a tweak of my LINQ is in order?  Are there values I can extract out via reflection or somethng to find out what was hit?

Comment: I can only see 1 Where clause.

Comment: @YoryeNathan I am using EF and LINQ is the logical choice.

Comment: @HenkHolterman as I mentioned, I stripped out the other WHERE clauses to make it more readable.

Comment: You strip the Where parts from a question about _which Where_ clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to decide - do you want three select branches (well actually it'll be two nested `?:` statements I should think)?  Or do you want to select one object that has all the potential members?  Personally, to avoid having to use concrete types in your `select` statement, or using `dynamic` I would just expand your anonymous type:

You can use `let` to do the `Contains` checks just once, and then use those both in your `where` clause and in the assignments of the anonymous type's members:

```
 /* .... */
 let coContains = co.Name.Contains(HaveCompany ? Company : co.Name)
 let bContains = b.Name.Contains(HaveCompany ? Company : b.Name)
 let gContains = g.Name.Contains(HaveCompany ? Company : g.Name)
 where co.Active == true
 && ( coContains || bContains || gContains )
 select new {
   /* sticking the booleans on there as well - might not want to do that */
   CoContains = coContains,
   BContains = bContains,
   GContains = gContains,
   /* other properties as per your code example */
   CompanyID = co.ID,
   BillTo = !gContains && bContains ? b : (BillTo)null,
   Generator = gContains && !bContains ? g : (Generator)null,
   Name = co.Name
 }).ToList();
```

So you're still returning the same data (as the comment says you might not actually want those extra 
booleans, I've only put them in there because it might simplify any control-flow logic you run afterwards) but you're only assigning them if the booleans match (what I think are) your criteria.  The `BillTo` and `Generator` properties will be `null` (I've assumed the type names here) if they shouldn't have been read.

Comment: OP wants the *projection* to be dependent on the outcome of the different `where` clauses` - a `let` clause doesn't help in this scenario

Comment: @BrokenGlass - well it might; but I take your point :)  I'm not entirely sure it's clear what is wanted, but I'll see if I can come up with something

Comment: You can use the boolean variables in the projection. Why wouldn't that be possible, Andras Zoltan?

Comment: @BrokenGlass I actually think the question is best served with a single projection where the two members which should be assigned conditionally are always included, but only assigned according to the values of those booleans.

Comment: @usr if you mean doing something like - `select bContains ? new { BillTo = blah } : gContains ? new { Generator = blah } : new { blah }` then it can't be done - they all have to be convertible to the same type; making anonymous types unusable unless you revert to `dynamic` or some reflection/gnarly type mangling solution.  You could create some concrete types over a common interface instead - but that seems pretty heavyweight for what is actually quite a simple problem.

Comment: You can do this: field = b ? null : someObj;

Comment: @usr - which is what my answer says (edited before my previous comment :) )

Answer (score 0):

If you're discerning which criteria was met, you may be partitioning data instead of filtering it.  Partitioning is the job of GroupBy.  Then you can do conditional group projection based on key.

```
.GroupBy(x =>  x.co.Name.Contains(HaveCompany ? Company : co.Name)  ? 1 :
  x.b.Name.Contains(HaveCompany ? Company : b.Name) ? 2 :
  x.gen.Name.Contains(HaveCompany ? Company : gen.Name) ? 3 :
  0
)
.SelectMany(g =>
g.Key == 1 ? g.Select(x => new {
  CompanyID = x.co.ID,
  BillTo = x.b,
  Generator = x.gen,
  Name = co.Name
} :
g.Key == 2 ? g.Select(x => new {
  CompanyID = co.ID,
  BillTo = b,
  Generator = (Generator) null,
  Name = co.Name
} :
g.Key == 3 ? g.Select(x => new {
  CompanyID = co.ID,
  BillTo = (BillTo) null,
  Generator = gen,
  Name = co.Name
} :
g.Where(x => false)
)
```